# How to add text to the Mocha output reports

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I want to track some values, like timings and [gasused](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#returns-41). I can return this using `console.log()`, collecting it, is not the problem. But would like a more robust and nicer method to report it than `console.log()`.

A simplyfied example:

```
it("I can reserve up to 10.000", async() => {
  let instance = await FullCoupon.new(10000);
  // in reality this is a helper function to collect and output the values.
  var tx = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(instance.transactionHash);
  console.log(tx.gasUsed);
  //...
});
```

The above example would print inline and unpadded number (the 53855 in the screenshot):  [image: screenshot]

What I am looking for, is, preferably to collect messages during the test-run and print them below the test-output. Where my test-suite prints the `> No events were emitted` for example.

Or, alternatively, to add texts to the test-line being printed, similar to the slow-test-timing flags, the `(185ms)` for example.

Does Mocha offer an API to set messages to be printed into its reports?

Comment: did you ever find an all reporter compatible solution?  For me some tests exit early if the browser/device doesn't support a feature. I'd like to see a message in the output the test was effectively skipped.

Comment: Thinking out loud, I guess I could make adding the tests conditional and if they aren't added and I want a message I could do `it('no support for x', _ => true)`

Answer (score 4):

There certainly is a way of doing it. You can use some other reporter which supports this kind of feature. You can try using [mochaawesome](https://adamgruber.github.io/mochawesome/) it has a feature to add details to individual test result.

To add some test to your test report, you can use code as below:

```
const addContext = require('mochawesome/addContext');
```

From inside it block:

```
addContext(<value you want to print>);
```

To use this reporter use `--reporter mochawesome` while triggering your test suite.

This will print the text in test report. There are other reporters as well which support this kind of features. Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Using a new and different reporter (HTML/CSS) just to be able to add some lines to a test, is a bit overkill, IMHO. But I've read the source of `addContext` and it has some good ideas on where to search. Thanks.